# how to add multi select option in custom module in magneto 2?

Tags: magento-2.0

i need to add multi selection dropdown.
am tried this below code. but it not bind the values in dropdown.how to do it?

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'select_product',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'label' => __('Select Product'),
                'title' => __('Select Product'),
                'name' => 'select_product',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => $this->_status->getOptionArray(),
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$options[1]['value'] = 'value here'; 

$options[1]['label'] = 'this is value';

        $fieldset->addField(
                'allowed_timeslots', 'multiselect', array(
            'name' => 'allowed_timeslots[]',
            'label' => __('Allowed Timeslot'),
            'title' => __('Alloewd Timeslot'),
            'values' => $options,
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => false
                )
        );
```

Please pass $options array in above format.

Answer (score 0):

@KapilSinghathia At some point at the end you have `$form->setValues($model->getData());`

> $form->setValues($model->getData());
>       $form->addValues(array('select_product'=> $options);
>       $form->addValues($model->getData());

It worked for me hope it helps!